# How to get database schema for Patterson's Eaglesoft database

Tags: sql-server, database-schema

**Background:** I am helping a dentist friend.  His dental business is growing and would like his patients to fill out the patient information form online.  Once the patient fills out the form, it can be exported to a .csv format.  We'd like to then import this into Easglesfot database.  This would create a new patient entry in the database and populate all the pertinent information from the .csv file.  Even after several conversations with the folks at Eaglesoft, we are unable to find any database information.  Patterson keeps their database "hidden", but it is a SQL database that we know.
**Question:** Is there any way to find out Eaglesoft's database schema?  Any help would be appreciated. -Suda

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420953/how-to-get-at-the-database-schema-of-a-hidden-db

Comment: You cannot rely on the internals of a system, only the supported/contractual/public interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get at the database schema of a hidden DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420953/how-to-get-at-the-database-schema-of-a-hidden-db)

Answer (score 0):

I use Sybase Central 6.1.0 on Eaglesoft V20. The later versions of Sybase Central don't work. Using the Database Navigator password (which you can get from Patterson Tech Support of you don't already have it) you can connect with Sybase Central and see tables, views, constraints, FKs, etc. You won't get a visual diagram like in DBeaver but it's a start. Use port 2638 when connecting to the DB.
HTH,
Vick