# How do I sync data from eaglesoft (dental software) to snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am working on trying to sync data. However, there doesn’t seem to be documentation on what database they use, or credentials to get access. Hoping someone might have worked with integration before and knows where I can connect?

I have looked through their website and can't seem to find anything.

Comment: did you try searching "eaglesoft" here on Stack Overflow, becuase the first couple of pages answer the "how to get" class of question, once you have the "data" now you are in the normal "how to load data into snowflake" question, which the Snowflake doc's can help with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420953/how-to-get-at-the-database-schema-of-a-hidden-db